# Reducir el tiempo de requests a APIs con la librería threading de Python

Tags: python

Estoy queriendo armar un screener de acciones del S&P 500, y para ello debo realizar un llamado a la web por cada ticker que contiene el índice. El tema es que serían 500 requests en total y el script me tarda cerca de 10 minutos en correr, teniendo el cuello de botella claramente cuando toca hacer los llamados a la API.

Para reducir este tiempo de trabajo quería armar algo con la librería threading, para realizar tareas en paralelo y demás, pero no logro que me haga todos los requests, me tira unos errores raros que no sé cómo interpretar y estoy un poco perdido. Estoy aprendiendo Python hace unos meses así que soy un principiante. Alguien me podría ayudar?

Adjunto el código:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import threading
yf.pdr_override()

tickers = si.tickers_sp500()
tickers = [item.replace(".", "-") for item in tickers]
index_name = "^GSPC"
start_date = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 365)
end_date = dt.date.today()

returns_multiples = []

index_df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(index_name, start_date, end_date)
index_df["Percent Change"] = index_df["Adj Close"].pct_change()
index_return = (index_df["Percent Change"] + 1).cumprod()[-1]

n_threads = 4
subs = np.array_split(tickers, n_threads)

dfs = {}

def worker(tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date, end_date)
        dfs[ticker] = df.to_dict()
        
        df["Percent Change"] = df["Adj Close"].pct_change()
        stock_return = (df["Percent Change"] + 1).cumprod()[-1]
        
        returns_multiple = round(stock_return/index_return, 2)
        returns_multiples.extend([returns_multiple])    
    return df

threads = []
for i in range(n_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target = worker, args = (subs[i],))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(dfs["AAPL"])
```

Y esto es lo que me tira cuando lo ejecuto:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completedException in thread Thread-16:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run

  File "C:\Users\migue\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 35, in worker
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migue\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 35, in worker
    vol_neg.append(vol_list[i])
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 138, in download
    vol_neg.append(vol_list[i])
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 138, in download
    return shared._DFS[shared._ISINS.get(ticker, ticker)]
KeyError: 'PRU'
    return shared._DFS[shared._ISINS.get(ticker, ticker)]
KeyError: 'J'

[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completedException in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migue\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 35, in worker
    vol_neg.append(vol_list[i])
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 138, in download
    return shared._DFS[shared._ISINS.get(ticker, ticker)]
KeyError: 'AAL'


[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completedException in thread Thread-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migue\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 35, in worker
    vol_neg.append(vol_list[i])
  File "C:\Users\migue\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 138, in download
    return shared._DFS[shared._ISINS.get(ticker, ticker)]
KeyError: 'DFS'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\migue\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 54, in <module>
    print(dfs["AAPL"])

KeyError: 'AAPL'
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!